# Get all possible pairs of n elements without duplicates with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

## What I need

I need all possible pairs of n elements without duplicates. Let's say I've these arrays:

```
$arr1 = [2, 4, 6, 7];
$arr2 = [6, 5, 4, 11];
$arr3 = [22, 1, 5, 8];

$final = [
    'a' => $arr1, 
    'b' => $arr2, 
    'c' => $arr3
];
```

What I now need is:

```
$pairs = [
    'ab' => [$arr1, $arr2],
    'ac' => [$arr1, $arr3],
    'bc' => [$arr2, $arr3]
];
```

## What I got

I come until this point:

```
function getPairs($array) {
    $n = count($array);

    $finalArray = [];
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($array as $a) {
        for ($x = $n-1; 0 <= $x; $x--) {
            if ($i != $x) {
                $finalArray[] = [$array[$i], $array[$x]];
            }
        }
        $i++;
    }

    return $finalArray;
}
```

And then:

```
$arr1 = [2, 4, 6, 7];
$arr2 = [6, 5, 4, 11];
$arr3 = [22, 1, 5, 8];

$merged = [$arr1, $arr2, $arr3];

$pairs = getPairs($merged);
```

There are two problems with my approach:

1. The loop produces `$x = 0`, `$i = 1` and later `$i = 1`, `$x = 0`, which results and a duplicated array.
2. I don't get the keys (`ab`, `ac`, `cb`) with this.

Similiar to this question but with array keys: [Get all the combinations of N elements of multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233874/get-all-the-combinations-of-n-elements-of-multidimensional-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid duplicates, guarantee that one member of the pair always has the *"lower"* key. This will avoid getting pairs `ac` and `ca`.

To get the letter keys you want, use `array_keys()` to extract the keys from the original arrays.

```
function getPairs($array) {
    $n = count($array);  
    $keys = array_keys($array);  
    $finalArray = [];
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($array as $a) {
        for ($x = $n-1; $i < $x; $x--) {
            $key1 = $keys[$i];
            $key2 = $keys[$x];
            $finalArray[$key1.$key2] = [$array[$key1], $array[$key2]];
        }
        $i++;
    }    
    return $finalArray;
}
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/LfSZ4)

Comment: "always guarantee that one member of the pair always has the "lower" key." That was the missing piece. Thanks a lot, you are awesome!

Answer (score 1):

This code should work if I understand the task properly:

```
$a = [[2, 4, 6, 7],[6, 5, 4, 11],[22, 1, 5, 8]];
$result = [];
$n = count($a);

for($i = 0; $i < $n-1; $i++) {
    for($j = $i+1; $j < $n; $j++) {
        $result[(string)$i.(string)$j] = [$a[$i], $a[$j]];
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Thanks my friend, but the keys were missing. @BeetleJuice is correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "hybrid" of the other two answers:

```php
$arr1 = [2, 4, 6, 7];
$arr2 = [6, 5, 4, 11];
$arr3 = [22, 1, 5, 8];

$final = [
    'a' => $arr1, 
    'b' => $arr2, 
    'c' => $arr3
];

$n = count($final);
$keys = array_keys($final);

$pairs = [];
for($i = 0; $i < $n-1; $i++) {
    for($j = $i+1; $j < $n; $j++) {
        $pairs[$keys[$i] . $keys[$j]] = [$final[$keys[$i]], $final[$keys[$j]]];
    }
}

print_r($pairs);
```